# Constructing an OData protocol specific URL

Tags: rest, odata

There are two entitySets Categories and products in a url.I want to get the products associated with the category.Also only 'Name' Property of Categories table and only 'Product_Id' Property of Products table should be returned.

What will be the OData Specific URL for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct URL to do the same

```
http://rootURI/Categories?$select=Name,Products/Product_Id&$expand=Products
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following URL:
`http://host/Categories?$select=Name&$expand=Products($select=Product_Id)`